# view the maximum equal cost paths configured for OSPF

Tags: cisco, ios, ospf

How do you check if the maximum number of equal cost paths has been modified (with the `(config-router)# maximum-paths` command)? Is the only way by viewing the running configuration?

`show ip ospf` doesn't seem to tell me anything about this.

Comment: As far as I know it's the only way--you can tell intrinsically by issuing a 'show ip cef <dest> internal' which will only show at most maximum-path's but it doesn't spit back the number.

Comment: Interesting. I was asking because sometimes on tests theyll only allow certain commands so I like to find every possible way to discover info.